# Compilar usando o Terminal em Lua

Tags: lua

Estou inicializando agora os estudos da linguagem de programação `Lua`, mas estou com uma dificuldade, quando faço um programa em c para compilar o algoritmo no terminal escrevo:

`**gcc nome-do-programa.c**` e depois coloco `**./a.out**`

e ele trás um valor ou algo parecido depende do que esta sendo pedido, em lua devo escrever **lua nome-do-programa** e "deveria fazer o que meu script estivesse pedindo e trazer o resultado", mas não e o que ele trás sinto que está faltando alguma coisa.

Comment: Raiane: Você pode editar a pergunta e colocar o código lua que você está tentando executar? Acredito que fique mais fácil para tentar ajudar

Answer (score 1):

```
./a.out x y z
```

recebe os strings `"x"`, `"y"`, `"z"` em `argv`, começando em `argv[1]`.

Isso funciona exatamente da mesma forma em Lua:

```
lua myscript.lua x y z
```

recebe os strings `"x"`, `"y"`, `"z"` em `arg`, começando em `arg[1]`.

Note que é `arg` em Lua, não `argv`.

Comment: O vararg também não tem essa funcionalidade não? `...`